# Really Remapping Bad Blocks on disk

Tags: linux, smartctl, badblocks, sata

I have a SATA drive which has a total of 8 bad blocks identified by the `badblocks` program. Supposedly the drive firmware should be able to remap them and substitute spares. I've run `badblocks` in `-n` mode to rewrite the partition in question, and run e2fsck multiple times. Nothing changes, always the same 8 bad blocks.

When I run `smartctl` it shows the `Reallocated_Sector_Ct` at `0`.

How can I get the firmware to actually remap the 8 bad blocks?

Answer (score 6):

The drive can only attempt to re-write or re-allocate unreadable sectors if new data is provided in a write request for the full sector. `badblocks` does not do that, and so, nothing whatsoever changes.

The "non-destructive" read-write mode works along these lines:

1. read original data
2. write test pattern
3. read test pattern
4. write original data

If this already fails in the first step, i.e. no data could be read, then no write can performed for that sector either, as there is no way to restore original data afterwards. This would be a destructive write, but you specifically requested the non-destructive variant, so it's not done.

The "non-destructive" method can still fail to restore original data for other reasons too, so you should never run badblocks on a drive you want to keep data, anyway.

---

If you want to do this with `badblocks` regardless, then you have to make use of its `-w` write-mode — which by default overwrites all your data, so you want to narrow down the range to the specific sector ranges that should be overwritten using the `badblocks -w device [last_block [first_block]]` optional parameter form. You can determine those sectors by running a read-only badblocks test first.

Readonly test:

```
# badblocks /dev/foobar
1000
```

Block 1000 is defective, so overwrite this block specifically:

```
# badblocks -w /dev/foobar 1000 1000
```

However, **this will still fail**. Why? Because `badblocks` uses a default blocksize of 1024 bytes.

This is wrong for devices with 512-byte sector size — badblocks would overwrite two sectors instead of one, causing additional damage — and also wrong for devices with 4096-byte sectors — badblocks would write one partial sector only, which does not work for reallocating sectors as you have to write a full block of data.

---

So for both commands above, you have to specify the correct blocksize (physical sector size) of your drive (512 or 4096 or maybe something else).

With changed blocksize the reported block numbers change accordingly:

```
# badblocks -b 512 /dev/foobar
2000
# badblocks -b 4096 /dev/foobar
250
```

And you can adapt the write commands accordingly:

```
# badblocks -b 512 -w /dev/foobar 2000 2000
# badblocks -b 4096 -w /dev/foobar 250 250
```

This should give the drive a chance to reallocate the offending sector.

---

If it still fails there is another possiblity: if the given device is a partition or otherwise logical drive and it's not aligned to the physical drive, all writes would turn out to be non-aligned so you'd end up writing 4096 bytes to two partial 4096-byte sectors.

It would not relocate the targeted sector and instead partially damage data in an adjacent sector.

So there is a certain risk of causing further data loss with this method.

Comment: The good news is that using -w badblocks did elimiate my 2 bad 4K blocks. They don't show up when I rescan the whole partition with badblocks in read mode. However, smartctl still shows the Reallocated_Sector_Ct at 0, and e2fsck gives "Updating bad block inode" every time I run it. Assuming the bad block is really gone, I expect to just re  mkfs the partition. Also clumsy fingers inadvertenly zapped the same bad block number in a different partition. Is there a way to tell what file contains that block number?

Comment: `e2fsck` "updating bad block inode" means you've _created_ one with one or more of your scans; there's now a filesystem table of blocks to be worked around. (Whether or not there's anything **in** it... well, you can use `dumpe2fs -b` to check. I'm not sure if it's possible to have an empty bad block list.) ...But that's all at the software level. If your drive hasn't reallocated by now, it's not likely to _after_ a remapping. Any blocks on the list will be dodged around like sinkholes by the filesystem. Nothing will be written to them anymore. (Not during normal use, anyway.)

Comment: drive not reallocating when the re-write succeeded is normal. you'll have to keep testing it regularly to see if they go back into a bad state again. if bad blocks are gone, `e2fsck -c` (but not `-k`) should clear it but it will do another full badblocks read for that.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to completely and intentionally ignore the issue.

The firmware will remap each sector when it's next written, and until then there's little point worrying about it.

Keep an eye on the other SMART attributes. Make sure you have good backups. Consider investing in a replacement disk.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the firmware to actually remap the 8 bad blocks?

You write to the damaged sector, e.g.

```
sudo hdparm --yes-i-know-what-i-am-doing --repair-sector SECTOR_NUMBER /dev/device
```

This is a destructive operation and it replaces the damaged sector with zeros (`0x00`).

S.M.A.R.T. is not so 'smart' after all, I've seen it fail more often than not. I.e. in most cases it fails to reallocate damaged sectors and it needs to be told what to do.

Comment: note that SECTOR_NUMBER for hdparm and numbers reported by badblocks will not be identical so you risk zeroing the wrong sectors

Comment: S.M.A.R.T. is used to report current status only, it cannot be used to modify the disk. As such, you have to use `fsck`, `hdparm` or `badblocks` to actually write to the disk fix remaps the broken sector if needed and the disk appears to work again.